# The number of members in the conceptual type does not match

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, devart, dotconnect

I am using entity framework code first with dotConnect for MySQL, and for some reason I get an error about one of my models mapping.

I've searched this error and it is usually caused by bad xml file or entity framework specific files. I am not using any of these, only a .cs code file with the models.

Exception Details:

> System.Data.MappingException: The number of members in the conceptual
>   type 'SiteModels.TournamentTable' does not match with the number of
>   members on the object side type 'SiteModels.TournamentTable'. Make
>   sure the number of members are the same.

I have no idea why I am getting this error, since I don't have any designer,
only one file containing the code.

**Here is the problematic class:**

```
public class TournamentTable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

public List<TournamentColumn> Columns { get; set; }

public TournamentTable()
{
    Columns = new List<TournamentColumn>();
}

public void AddColumn(int index, TournamentColumn column)
{
    Columns.Insert(index, column);
}

public void RemoveColumn(int index)
{
    Columns.RemoveAt(index);
}

/// <summary>
/// Add a tournament cell at the top of the column.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="column"></param>
public void AddColumn(TournamentColumn column)
{
    Columns.Add(column);
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns the tournament column at the index specified.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="index"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public TournamentColumn this[int index]
{
    get { return Columns[index]; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns the tournament cell at the index specified.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="columnIndex"></param>
/// <param name="cellIndex"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public TournamentCell this[int columnIndex, int cellIndex]
{
    get { return Columns[columnIndex][cellIndex]; }
    set
    {

        Columns[columnIndex][cellIndex] = value;
    }
}
```

}

Context configuration:

```
public class EntitiesContext : DbContext
{

    public EntitiesContext()
        : base()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<EntitiesContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EntitiesContext>());
    }

public EntitiesContext(DbConnection connection)
    : base(connection, true)
{
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions
      .Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions
        .ColumnTypeCasingConvention>();
}

public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
public DbSet<TournamentTable> TournamentTables { get; set; }
```

}

Thanks for the help, I don't have any clue.

Comment: Try commenting out the indexers and see if it helps. If it does you may need to put NotMapped attribute on them or reimplement them as methods.

Comment: The NotMapped attribute did the trick :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try commenting out the indexers and see if it helps. If it does you may need to put NotMapped attribute on them or reimplement them as methods.